# Решение уравнения методом хорд и методом половинного деления отрезка(метод дихотомии)

Tags: c++, математика

Всем привет! Написал две функции для решения уравнения методом Хорд и методом Дихотомии, но проблема в том, что результаты не совпадают.
Вот мои написанные функции:

```
double chord_method(double a, double b, double e) {  // метод хорд
double next = 0;
double tmp;

do{
    tmp = next;
    next = b - F(b) * (a - b) / (F(a) - F(b));
    a = b;
    b = tmp;
} 
while (abs(next - b) > e);
return next;
```

}

```
double dichotomy_method(double a, double b, double eps) { //метод дихотомии
double c;
while ((b - a) / 2 > eps) {
    c = (a + b) / 2;
    if ((F(a) * F(c)) > 0) {
        a = c;
    }
    else {
        b = c;
    }
}
return c;
```

}

И дано, например, следующее уравнение:

```
double F(double x) {
return x * x * x + 4 * x - 3;
```

}

Отрезок, на котором надо вычислить: от a = 0 до b = 1, точность e = 0.001.
Ответы при таких аргументах следующие: Методом Хорд получается: 0.6, Методом Дихотомии: 0.673828.

А вот с с таким уравнением, с той же точность, но на отрезке [2, 10]:

```
double F(double x) {
return x * x * x - 18 * x - 83;
```

}

Результаты следующие: Методом Хорд: 5.70511, Методом Дихотомии: 5.70508.

Вопрос такой: Что не так с этими функциями? Формулы, вроде, нашел подходящие, но результаты не совпадают точь в точь. Или же с точки зрения математики все нормально?

Comment: В первом случае решения на заданном отрезке вообще нет, а у вас такая ситуация никак не обрабатывается. Хорды вываливаются за диапазон, а дихотомия упирается в ограничение справа.

Comment: Окей, спасибо, сам не заметил, что в первом случае не тот интервал выбрал.
Т.е. функции, в принципе, описаны правильно, осталось только описать ситуации, когда нет решений, так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Немного исправьте код, и все у вас получится. И лучше писать не глобальную функцию, а передавать ее в метод в качестве параметра. См. https://ideone.com/8H2Fqq

```
double chord(double a, double b, double e, double (*f)(double))
{  // метод хорд

    double fa = f(a), fb = f(b);
    if (fa*fb > 0) throw runtime_error("Wrong data");

    for(;abs(b-a) > e;)
    {
        double x = a - (b-a)*fa/(fb-fa);
        b = a;
        fb = fa;
        a = x;
        fa = f(x);
    }
    return a;
}

double dichotomy(double a, double b, double e, double (*f)(double))
{ //метод дихотомии
    double fa = f(a), fb = f(b);
    if (fa*fb > 0) throw runtime_error("Wrong data");

    for(;abs(b - a) > e;)
    {
        double x = (a + b)/2;
        if (f(x)*fa > 0)  a = x;
        else              b = x;
    }
    return (a+b)/2;
}
```

Comment: Cпасибо! В своем коде я так и передавал, просто тут решил вот так.